# Hibernate AOP Transaction and java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, aop

I have a problem with my transaction, after some inactivity between some request my code throw an exception:

```
 [DEBUG] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Could not set JDBC Connection read-only
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408) ~[Util.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383) ~[Util.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023) ~[SQLError.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997) ~[SQLError.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983) ~[SQLError.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928) ~[SQLError.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1323) ~[ConnectionImpl.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1315) ~[ConnectionImpl.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:5510) ~[ConnectionImpl.class:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setReadOnly(DelegatingConnection.java:377) ~[DelegatingConnection.class:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setReadOnly(PoolingDataSource.java:338) ~[PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.class:1.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(DataSourceUtils.java:155) [DataSourceUtils.class:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:432) [HibernateTransactionManager.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372) [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.class:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417) [TransactionAspectSupport.class:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255) [TransactionAspectSupport.class:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) [TransactionInterceptor.class:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [ReflectiveMethodInvocation.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [ExposeInvocationInterceptor.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [ReflectiveMethodInvocation.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [JdkDynamicAopProxy.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getGuards(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at com.futuresoft.guardmanager.web.controller.GuardConfigurationController.getUserGuards(GuardConfigurationController.java:147) [GuardConfigurationController.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214) [InvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [InvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690) [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) [AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) [DispatcherServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876) [DispatcherServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [FrameworkServlet.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [FilterSecurityInterceptor.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [FilterSecurityInterceptor.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [ExceptionTranslationFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [SessionManagementFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [RequestCacheAwareFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [BasicAuthenticationFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [LogoutFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [FilterChainProxy.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [FilterChainProxy.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.9]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 123 889 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 28 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408) ~[Util.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137) ~[SQLError.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3715) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3604) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4149) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834) ~[ConnectionImpl.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2783) ~[ConnectionImpl.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569) ~[StatementImpl.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getUserName(DatabaseMetaData.java:7013) ~[DatabaseMetaData.class:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.toString(DelegatingConnection.java:123) ~[DelegatingConnection.class:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.toString(PoolingDataSource.java:355) ~[PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.class:1.4]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(DataSourceUtils.java:153) ~[DataSourceUtils.class:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3161) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3615) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3604) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4149) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776) ~[MysqlIO.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834) ~[ConnectionImpl.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2783) ~[ConnectionImpl.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569) ~[StatementImpl.class:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getUserName(DatabaseMetaData.java:7013) ~[DatabaseMetaData.class:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.toString(DelegatingConnection.java:123) ~[DelegatingConnection.class:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.toString(PoolingDataSource.java:355) ~[PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.class:1.4]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(DataSourceUtils.java:153) ~[DataSourceUtils.class:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 81 more
```

i use aop transaction with spring and hibernate :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- MySQL data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="distanturl" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="value" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>orm/User.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut" expression="execution(* my.package.services.*service.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

my connection seem to be properly closed by the transaction, so i don't understand why i encouter this error. Is anyone have an idea ?

**EDIT: Solved ! see below !**

Answer (score 0):

ok i solve my problem.

After some idle time, the distant database closed my connection but my application wasn't aware of that. So, the next transaction failed with the EOFException.

To solve the problem i use a validation query launch during idle time. This validation close all the connection after some inactivity.

see my hibernate configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- MySQL data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jmyurl" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="5" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="5" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="20000" />        
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>orm/User.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut" expression="execution(* mypackage.*Services.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

each 10 second i launch the validation request. And after 20second of inactivity, the connection is closed

more information here : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html